# Click on button with custom event with Ruby Mechanize

Tags: ruby, mechanize

I have a block of HTML code that contains a button

```
<button class="someButton" onclick="openPage('test')"></button>
```

I need to click on this button with Mechanize.
Mechanize has API to work with buttons via forms. But:

1. Mechanize can interact with buttons only via forms and there is not
   form, just a single button
2. Creating form manually does not allow to click on button because it supports only buttons that make submit

Is there any way how to click on button with custom event?

Comment: Does the button have any text associated with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mechanize doesn't do javascript so button events just get ignored. For that you need a full browser like watir, watir-webdriver, selenium-webdriver, celerity, capybara-webkit or one that I missed.

Comment: Thanks, I solved it in a different way with parsing the content of the onClick method and building link manually.